# Is it possible to make a mobile internet connection using a SIM-card in my HP Zbook laptop?

Tags: networking, 22.04, hp, wwan

I've inserted a twin card with an internet subscription.
But I just get "No WWAN-adapter found" when I go into Mobile network settings.

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.2.

```
$ mmcli -L
No modems were found
```

```
$ sudo lspci
[sudo] lösenord för ben: 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8730M]
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000 Series]
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

```
$ sudo lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0424:5534 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05c8:0369 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP HD Webcam
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 05ac:1402 Apple, Inc. Ethernet Adapter [A1277]
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0424:2134 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c062 Logitech, Inc. M-UAS144 [LS1 Laser Mouse]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: A bit more information will be needed to offer an answer. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're using (1) the terminal output of `sudo lspci` and `sudo lsusb`. With this, it should be possible to first identify if the OS can see the modem and then to determine if that modem is supported.

Comment: Thanks @matigo! I've added the information you suggested.

Comment: There does not appear to be a modem in either of those lists. Is it possible to enable/disable the modem with a key combination or in the UEFI/BIOS? If not, then the modem may not be compatible with Linux 

Comment: @matigo Is it possible to find out using the serial number of the machine? I can't seem to find it on hp support... Maybe somebody else can? These are photos of the serial tags inside the machine:
serial1: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fq7bm7l1at783q4/serial1.jpg?dl=0
serial2: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4wuwgqoxpkekxsw/serial2.jpg?dl=0